# passing structured data to php via post

Tags: php, javascript, post

Suppose I have the following data:

```
var arr = [], arr1 = [], arr2 = [], arr3 = [], arr4 = [];
var a = 'something', b = 'else';
arr1['key1-1'] = 'value1-2';
arr1['key1-2'] = 'value1-2';
for (var i = 0; i < someCond; i++) {
    arr = [];
    arr['key2-1'] = 'value2-1';
    arr['key2-2'] = 'value2-2';
    arr2.push(arr);
}
```

Now I need to pass the hole of it to a php script.

I packaged it into a single variable like so:

```
var postVar = {
    a: a,
    b: b,
    arr1: arr1,
    arr2: arr2
};
```

I'm using jQuery so I tried to post it like this:
**1)**

```
//Works fine for a and b, not for the arrays
$.post('ajax.php', postVar, function(response){});
```

and this:
**2)**

```
var postVar = JSON.stringify(postVar);
$.post('ajax.php', {json: postVar}, function(response){});
```

with the php file

```
$req = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['json']), true);
```

which also doesn't work.

How should I structure/format my data as to send it to PHP?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Case 1:
console.log(postVar);
[image: console.log(postVar)]


PHP print_r($_POST) response:
Array
(
    [a] => something
    [b] => else
)

As you can see, there are no arrays (objects) on the php side.

**Case 2:**
When I add the following:

```
    postVar = JSON.stringify(postVar);
    console.log(postVar);
```

I get
{"a":"something","b":"else","arr1":[],"arr2":[[],[],[]]} 
with console.log(postVar)

So that seems to be the problem in this case... right?

Comment: Why you put stripslashes here?

Comment: Have you checked to see if PHP is getting the data? ie just put `print_r($_POST)` in the PHP file. Also check the console for any hints.

Comment: Please check if magic_quotes is running on your server, it will messup with json

Comment: Please note that your "arrays" are not arrays but objects. PHP and Javascript is quite different in that sense. `arr1['key1-1']` is basically setting a property named `key1-1` on your array object. Please elaborate on "does not work". Is there an error? How do you try to access `$req`? Also check your Network tab in the Developer Tools of your browser. You need to know what is the actual data sent to the server.

Comment: Do not use HTML <pre> tags in the post, used the normal Markdown formatting.

Comment: On the client side, try using `JSON.stringify()` (If I have spelt it correctly). The on the server side, you can use `json_decode()`.

Comment: By "does not work" I mean that I cannot access the arrays (or objects) on the PHP side. Please look at the edited section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, although Arrays *are* Objects, JSON.stringify ignores non Array properties on Arrays. So I had to explicitly declare all variables as objects. Except for arr2 that is really used as an array.

Here goes the full code:

```
var arr = {}, arr1 = {}, arr2 = [];
var a = 'something', b = 'else';
arr1['key1-1'] = 'value1-2';
arr1['key1-2'] = 'value1-2';
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr = {};
    arr['key2-1'] = 'value2-1';
    arr['key2-2'] = 'value2-2';
    arr2.push(arr);
}

var postVar = {
    a: a,
    b: b,
    arr1: arr1,
    arr2: arr2
};


postVar = JSON.stringify(postVar);
$.post('ajax.php', {json: postVar}, function(response){});
```

And on the PHP side:

```
$req = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
print_r($req);
```

Hope this helps others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for magic_quotes before add stripslashes like that

```
if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
    $jsonString = stripslashes( $jsonString );
}
$data = json_decode( $jsonString );
```

i suggest that you should turn off magic quotes... it's not magic at all